# Почему цикл возвращает код выхода 1

Tags: bash

Есть строка, она работает как надо

```
for var in $(find ./temp_files/fetch/*/configuration -type f); do diff $var ./temp_files/file-1commit >> ./temp_files/diff; done
```

но вот почему то возвращает код выхода не 0, а 1. Когда я пытаюсь ее выполнить в пайплайне, он падает

```
 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: У вас там `set -e` где-то?  Вы же в курсе, что когда файлы различаются, `diff` возвращает `1`?

Comment: Не знал, а можно это как то обойти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно проигнорировать код ответа от `diff`, можете
сделать так:

```sh
for var in $(find ./temp_files/fetch/*/configuration -type f)
do
    diff "$var" ./temp_files/file-1commit >> ./temp_files/diff || :
done
```